# Error occurs when i set connectToSortable inside the drag function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to drag an object and then connect it to 1 of 4 sortable divs.  The issue is that since i dont know what the div is, i wrote a script that will, in the drag check to see if the item is in the bounds of a valid option.  When it is, it sets the connectToSortable accordingly, but then it crashes.

It when it sets `$(this).draggable("option", "connectToSortable", "#"+$(tar).attr("id"));` it fails.  I was thinking that somehow the draggable object was destroyed, but the big issue is that i cant see where it is broken.  The Console is giving me solid logic.

http://jsfiddle.net/mjYt2/

has my example where an error says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Maybe i am just doing this horrendously wrong?   My goal is to drag an object into a lsit of sortablables.  So it will go into the first div, and sort around with "hello" and "World"  or it will go to the second and sort about that "hello" and "world".

**EDIT:**  It seems that in my example, the error does not occur if i comment out the inline code as stated above.  Something errors there causing the "length" of undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

If you assign all the items a class that are sortable, you can then just say:

```
$(item).draggable({
      helper:'clone', 
      connectToSortable:'.comma,.delimited,#list,#of > .selectors'
});
```

it seems that i was overthinking it.